# Firefox WebDriver fails to accept untrusted certificates

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to access SSL-protected site with invalid certificate (unknown issuer). I followed instructions and configured Firefox

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver(profile));
```

But I keep getting

> An error occurred during a connection to somedomain.com. SSL
>   peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.
>   Error code: SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

I'm using FirefoxWebDriver 2.48.2 with Firefox 45.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer is likely the problem.  It is easy to find out if a certificate has expired or does not match the host from which it was served, but hard to find out if the issuer of the certificate is untrusted.  Setting setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer to true means assume untrusted which is the opposite of what you want.  Try:

```
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
```

Comment: @dzieciou Did you try my answer? If not, what fixed it?

Comment: it doesnt seem to work for mine..

Answer (score 0):

Try two options:

- Upgrade your browser
- Ask the server maintainer to upgrade the security certificates.